# Identify input file from PolyBase query in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

When selecting from an external table in SQL Server 2016, where the location of the data source is defined as a WASB folder, is it possible to return a column with the file name the record was identified in?

Similar to how INPUT__FILE__NAME would work in Hive?

Answer (score 0):

at the moment it is not possible, [see link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/suggestions/11338512-expose-file-properties-as-additional-columns-in-ex)

Comment: Also see this similar feedback request: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/suggestions/13749543-function-that-returns-the-name-of-the-current-file